# Download files in laravel using Response::download

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In the Laravel application, I'm trying to achieve a button inside the view that can allow users to download files without navigating to any other view or route
Now I have two issues:
(1) below function throwing

```
The file "/public/download/info.pdf" does not exist
```

(2) The Download button should not navigate the user anywhere and rather just download files on the same view, My current settings, route a view to '/download'

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

Button:

```
  <a href="/download" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/download', 'HomeController@getDownload');
```

Controller :

```
public function getDownload(){
        //PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf
        $file="./download/info.pdf";
        return Response::download($file);
}
```

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Try this.

```
public function getDownload()
{
    //PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf
    $file= public_path(). "/download/info.pdf";

    $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            );

    return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```

`"./download/info.pdf"`will not work as you have to give full physical path.

**Update 20/05/2016**

Laravel 5, 5.1, 5.2 or 5.* users can use the following method instead of `Response` facade. However, my previous answer will work for both Laravel 4 or 5. (the `$header` array structure change to associative array `=>`- the colon after 'Content-Type' was deleted - if we don't do those changes then headers will be added in wrong way: the name of header wil be number started from 0,1,...)

```
$headers = [
              'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
           ];

return response()->download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
```

Comment: Any way to return a file download AND update the view?

Comment: Can I change the file permissions while downloading only? @Anam

Comment: @EswaraReddy, You mean on fly? I don't think so.

Comment: How can I download anytype of file?

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan you only need to change `Content-type`, file name and file path to do that.

Comment: @Anam How will I know the content type where I may have any type of file?

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan just use `return Response::download($pathToFile);`

Comment: @Anam is there any way we can pass remote url as filepath ?

Comment: how can you make this dynamic like get the id of a certain table and download the image in it?

Answer (score 54):

File downloads are super simple in **Laravel 5**.

As @Ashwani mentioned Laravel 5 allows [file downloads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads) with `response()->download()` to return file for download. We no longer need to mess with any headers. To return a file we simply:

```
return response()->download(public_path('file_path/from_public_dir.pdf'));
```

from within the controller.

---

**Reusable Download Route/Controller**

Now let's make a reusable file download route and controller so we can server up any file in our `public/files` directory.

Create the controller:

```
php artisan make:controller --plain DownloadsController
```

Create the route in `app/Http/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/download/{file}', 'DownloadsController@download');
```

Make download method in `app/Http/Controllers/DownloadsController`:

```
class DownloadsController extends Controller
{
  public function download($file_name) {
    $file_path = public_path('files/'.$file_name);
    return response()->download($file_path);
  }
}
```

Now simply drops some files in the `public/files` directory and you can server them up by linking to `/download/filename.ext`:

```
<a href="/download/filename.ext">File Name</a> // update to your own "filename.ext"
```

If you pulled in [Laravel Collective's Html package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) you can use the Html facade:

```
{!! Html::link('download/filename.ext', 'File Name') !!}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks a lot @DutGRIFF, You saved my day. I tried this download thing for 5 hours but didn't work though, I didn't get any solution but when I tried your solution it worked like a charm. Laravel rocks.

Comment: this is the perfect code ! works like charming!

Answer (score 30):

In the accepted answer, for Laravel 4 the headers array is constructed incorrectly. Use:

```
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
);
```

Comment: the difference in the instantiation of the array is likely because of a PHP version, not laravel version  ;)

Answer (score 11):

Quite a few of these solutions suggest referencing the public_path() of the Laravel application in order to locate the file. Sometimes you'll want to control access to the file or offer real-time monitoring of the file. In this case, you'll want to keep the directory private and limit access by a method in a controller class. The following method should help with this:

```
public function show(Request $request, File $file) {

    // Perform validation/authentication/auditing logic on the request

    // Fire off any events or notifiations (if applicable)

    return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . $file->location));
}
```

There are other paths that you could use as well, described on
[Laravel's helper functions documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#paths)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I was getting an Http 500 error but this worked for my case.

Answer (score 8):

While using `laravel 5` use this code as you don`t need headers.

`return response()->download($pathToFile);` .

If you are using `Fileentry` you can use below function for downloading.

```
// download file
public function download($fileId){  
    $entry = Fileentry::where('file_id', '=', $fileId)->firstOrFail();
    $pathToFile=storage_path()."/app/".$entry->filename;
    return response()->download($pathToFile);           
}
```

Comment: This answer would be helpful if it left out the unnecessary parts or even just expanded on them below the pure answer. `Fileentry` is a different feature not needed for this question. Edit answer and I will upvote because the mentioning of LV5s `response()->download()`.

Answer (score 8):

I think that you can use

```
$file= public_path(). "/download/info.pdf";

$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type( $file ),
    );
```

With this you be sure that is a pdf.

Answer (score 8):

HTML href link click:

```
<a ="{{ route('download',$name->file) }}"> Download  </a>
```

In controller:

```php
public function download($file){
    $file_path = public_path('uploads/cv/'.$file);
    return response()->download( $file_path);
}
```

In route:

```
Route::get('/download/{file}','Controller@download')->name('download');
```

Answer (score 3):

// Try this to download any file. laravel 5.*

// you need to use facade "use Illuminate\Http\Response;"

```
public function getDownload()
{

//PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf

    $file= public_path(). "/download/info.pdf";   

    return response()->download($file);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 HTML link click 
<a class="download" href="{{route('project.download',$post->id)}}">DOWNLOAD</a>


// Route

Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('file-download/{id}', 'PostController@downloadproject')->name('project.download');
});

public function downloadproject($id) {

        $book_cover = Post::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $path = public_path(). '/storage/uploads/zip/'. $book_cover->zip;
        return response()->download($path, $book_cover
            ->original_filename, ['Content-Type' => $book_cover->mime]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is html part

```
 <a href="{{route('download',$details->report_id)}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary download" data-report_id="{{$details->report_id}}" >Download</a>
```

This is Route :

```
Route::get('/download/{id}', 'users\UserController@getDownload')->name('download')->middleware('auth');
```

This is function :

```
public function getDownload(Request $request,$id)
{
                $file= public_path(). "/pdf/";  //path of your directory
                $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type: application/pdf',
                );
                 return Response::download($file.$pdfName, 'filename.pdf', $headers);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the JavaScript download functionality then you can also do

```html
 <a onclick="window.open('info.pdf) class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-download-alt"> </i> Download Brochure </a>
```

Also remember to paste the info.pdf file in your public directory of your project

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply inside your controller:
`return response()->download($filePath);`
Happy coding :)