# Laravel Response::download throws a FileNotFoundException exception when using URL::to

Tags: laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and want to make a download response using `Response::download`. So I used the following code:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive',
);
return Response::download(URL::to("assets/install.apk"), "tracking.apk", $headers);
```

But I got a `FileNotFoundException` exception. Then, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415796/1922137) and changed my codes to:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive',
);
return Response::download(public_path() . "/assets/install.apk", "tracking.apk", $headers);
```

Now, it works. However, my question is what was wrong with `URL::to`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response::download` expects a file system path such as `/srv/http/some/file` rather than an URL which would be `http://hostname/some/file`.

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses) :

```
Response::download($pathToFile);
```

You can also use optional parameters to set the name of the file that'll be saved on the client's side and an array additional headers like so :

```
Response::download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
```