# Laravel 5 - File Download failed issue

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5, download

I'm new to Laravel 5.4 and I need to download few PDF files from its database. There's an issue downloading the files.

[image]

Here is my controller.

```
 public function download_files(){
    $dowaloads=DB::table('dowanloadable_files')->get();
    return view('dowanload.dowanload', compact('dowaloads'));
}
```

Here is my view.

```
 <tbody> 
    @foreach($dowaloads as $download)
     <tr>
      <td>{{ $download->file_title }}</td>
      <td><a href="download/{{ $download->file_name }}" download="{{ $download->file_name }}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Dowanload</button></a></td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

i place all these PDF files in public/download directory as well but this problem not changed. Is this due to no files in the database?

Here is the database screen.
[image]

Here is my download directory .
[image]

Comment: Show your download folder.

Comment: Sir, download folder means?when i press download and then downloading place? or just download directory?

Comment: Just download directory.

Comment: Where are you handling the download request on the code? Like when some one presses the download link, what's the route and controller for that? Can you show us the code. For reference see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415444/download-files-in-laravel-using-responsedownload

Comment: @LuzanBaral actually i dont know how to do that,i just follow the youtube tutorial .can you please suggest me it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong folder name use like this, seen in your download folder image.

```
  <td><a href="/dowanload/{{ $download->file_name }}" download="/dowanload/{{ $download->file_name }}"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Dowanload</button></a></td>
```