# Force download of PDF in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, download

On a page I have a link:

```
<a href="{{ route('downloadWirebird',[$mag->id]) }}" target="_blank" title="download PDF">@fa('download')</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

and in the web.php I have:

```
Route::get('downloadWirebird/{id}','FrontController@downloadWirebird')->name('downloadWirebird');
```

In FrontController I have:

```
public function downloadWirebird($id)
                {
                  $wbd = Wirebird::find($id);
                  $fileName = asset('Wirebird')."/".$wbd->PDF;
                  $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];
                  return response()->download($fileName, $headers);
                }
```

All the paths are correct but when I click on the link absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: To download a file use the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10615916/3254405

Comment: I really was looking for the Laravel 5.5 answer

Comment: True, then may be your notation is wrong the way you put column separator in headers but an arrow after response(), try sticking to either columns or arrows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415796/3254405

Comment: Have amend the controller to

    $wbd = Wirebird::find($id);
    $file= public_path()."/Wirebird";
    $headers = array(
                            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
                          );
     return response()->download($file, $wbd[0]['PDF'], $headers);

but still nothing works

Comment: Try to simplify, so get rid of Wirebird thing (not sure what it is), something like this example and include a facade library as it says, or just hard code a full path for testing, then check with Fiddler for raw headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821002/3254405

Comment: Can you please share a dd($wbd) ? What does $wbd->PDF print ?