# How to download pdf file in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have stored my pdf file in files folder inside public folder. Now, i have a "Download" button inside resources/views/admin/view_data.blade.php

How to download the pdf file when i click the download button??

Comment: [Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018803/2501581)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
When you click on the button call a route and a method then use this code. You can change directory path.

```
public function getDownload()
{
  //PDF file is stored under project/public/download/info.pdf
  $file= public_path(). "/download/info.pdf";

  $headers = array(
          'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );

    return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```

Comment: but i have five files...then how to give file name

Comment: You want to download five files at a time?

Comment: one file at a time

Comment: Put 5 file paths and their name to an array . ['name' => 'path'] .

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition, if you are using an IDE the following will prevent any squarks
`return response()->download($file, 'filename.pdf' ,$headers);`