# Download files from Laravel

Tags: php, linux, laravel, wget, endpoint

I would like create endpoint in Laravel which I can use in Linux to download zip archive.

I created:

```
public function download_templates()
{
    return response()->file(base_path() . '/sites/templates.zip');
}
```

But when I use:

```
wget http://linktopage.com/api/download_templates
```

In result I receive HTML code of endpoint.

Someone has idea?

Comment: Why not utilize laravel Storage::download($filepath);?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download files in laravel using Response::download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20415444/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this code if you are using 5.*

```
return response()->download(public_path('/sites/templates.zip'));
```

also, I changed `base_path()` to `public_path()`, so you have to put the file in Public, if not you can use the `base_path()` instead of `public_path()` in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize file download response should contain headers indicating that it's attachment otherwise browser will print content.

According to the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads) "file" method is used in case you want just to output file contents without downloading. For downloading there is method "download" which forces download.