# Image file doesn't want to download Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Output]When I run the code, the image I want to download from my folder appears in XHR -> preview in Chrome but doesn't want to start download. I use the code according to the Laravel doc:

```php
$file = public_path()."/files/projects/".$name;
$headers = array('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
return response()->download($file,$name,$headers);
```

I don't see what is wrong. It's pretty similar to many code I have seen.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error it's just doesn't want to download. It appears in  XHR -> preview in chrome only @sumit.

Comment: Just reading [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads), I see `...  requires the file being downloaded to have an ASCII file name` - could that be the problem?

Comment: Could you include the html of your page and explain the user actions required for downloading the image? This might not be a problem with your Laravel code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use headers and we have Laravel 5.1 but we do something a little different where we cache our files for a short time and create dynamic images of graphs using c3 plugin. At the end of my post I will show how we use these headers w/cache.

Make sure you add a route:

```
Route::get('/files/projects/{file}', 'DownloadController@index');
```

[See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415444/download-files-in-laravel-using-responsedownloadid#answer-20415796)

```
$file= public_path(). $name;
```

**Laravel < 5**

```
$headers = array(
          'Content-Type: image/jpeg',
        );

  return Response::download($file, $name.'jpg', $headers);
```

**Laravel >= 5**

```
  return response()->download($file, $name."jpg");
```

**NOTE:** Here is a cached image implementation ...(notice the base64_encode for binary files ie: .png .jpg)

```
  $responseHeaders = array(
            'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $outputFileName . '.png',
            'Expires' => '0',
            'Pragma' => 'public'
        );


$url = action('DownloadController@standAlone', ['cat' => $category]);

        // Values cached for 1 minute... ???
        if (Cache::has($url)){
            return Response(base64_decode(Cache::get($url)))->withHeaders($responseHeaders);
        } else {
            $maxWidth = 2560;
            $maxHeight = 854;
            $minWidth = 780;
            $minHeight = 260;

            if ($height > $maxHeight) {
                $height = $maxHeight;
            }

            if ($height < $minHeight) {
                $height = $minHeight;
            }

            if ($width > $maxWidth) {
                $width = $maxWidth;
            }

            if ($width < $minWidth) {
                $width = $minWidth;
            }

            $command = app_path('bin/phantomjs');
            $command .= ' ' . app_path('bin/maketrendpng.js');
            $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($url);
            $command .= ' /dev/stdout';
            $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($height);
            $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($width);
            $command .= ' ' . request()->server->get('SERVER_NAME');
            $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($_COOKIE[env('SESSION_COOKIE', 'laravel_session')]);
            $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg(env('SESSION_COOKIE', 'laravel_session'));

            $handle = popen($command, 'r');

            $contents = '';

            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
            }

            pclose($handle);

    Cache::put($url, base64_encode($contents), 1);

    return Response($contents)->withHeaders($responseHeaders);
```

Comment: I put my image in a folder in public and I tried the commands. And the code is the same thing. I don't work either.

Comment: Did you do a dd($file, $name); in your controller function to see the output? It is likely your variables arent correct or your absolute path is wrong.

Comment: Try adding the route to your custom `routes/web.php`