# When i tried to open .rtf files but it is opening as .zip

Tags: php, laravel, phpword

I am working with Laravel 5.8 and i am using phpword to creat .rtf file.
When i download it the it is opening as zip file. I changed the file type rtf to docx but  i got the same result. [image]

Comment: What content type do you send to the client?

Comment: I am not creating it with header. I just save template. here is my code. 


~~~
$templateProcessor->setUpdateFields(true);
$time = date('dmYhis');
$templateProcessor->saveAs(public_path('Report_File/Pci_ROC_' . $time . '.rtf'));
return response()->download(public_path('Report_File/Pci_ROC_' . $time . '.rtf'))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
~~~

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415796/3906760

Comment: Do other RTF files not generated via PHPWord open normally?

Comment: Yes Other RTF files not generated via PHPWord open normal.

Comment: @MrTux i tried that but it is not working for me

Comment: Then since this may be an issue with how the file is generated can you share the code you are using? Also try to save the file first and open it from the downloaded location to see if the issue persists.

Comment: When file saved and i opened it files opens normally. i got this  issue when i download the file and want to directly access from browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this bellow code i can manage to download the file as RTF instead of Zip archive.

Ok now I can manage to solve it with bellow code

```
############## Create RTF file ##############
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save(public_path('Report_File/InfoSec_DFAR_Report_' . $time . '.rtf'));
                ############## Create RTF file ##############
    
                ############## Download RTF file ##############
    
                header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for internet explorer
                header("Content-Type: application/rtf");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-Length:".filesize(public_path('Report_File/filename' . $time . '.rtf')));
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=InfoSec_DFAR_Report_".$time. '.rtf');
                readfile(public_path('Report_File/filename' . $time . '.rtf'));
                die(); 
############## Download RTF file ##############
```