# Laravel: Can't download the generated file

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I have a function where I generates excel (.csv) file. Everything is working except download.
So my idea was to download the file automatically in the browser after generating the csv file. When the file was generated we store it in the public folder.
So when I call my function , the function is opening the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/tools/export/exportData  and displaying the file instead of downloading it. So for this I need your help! Thank you in advance.
My codes :

```
public function exportData() {
 
$size=sizeof($arr);
   for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
   {
    fputcsv($fh,$arr[$i]);
   }
   fclose($fh);
   $file="Export.csv";
   $headers = array(

    'Content-Type: text/csv',

  );
   return response()->download($file, 'Export.csv', $headers);
  
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415796/2324206

Comment: @Haridarshan Thanks but  I tried but its displaying in the browser instead of downloading it..

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to your headers to indicate how to handle file:

```php
$headers = [
    'Content-type'        => 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="filename.csv"',
];
```

To display the file in the browser instead of downloading it, you would exchange `attachment` for `inline`.

Comment: Hello @marks thanks for your reply! I tried your code,  but it still displaying the file ..