# How to download file from storage app folder in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-storage

I want to download a file from Storage/app/public folder.

Somehow it doesn't work with out any error message.

Below is the code I've tried.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/viewAllFile',[DownloadController::class, 'downfunc']);
Route::post('download/{id}',[DownloadController::class, 'download']);
```

**DownloadController.php**

```
class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function downfunc()
    {
        $downloads = DB::table('files')->get();
        return view('download.viewfile', compact('downloads'));
    }

    public function download($file_name)
    {
        //Storage::disk('local')->put('example.txt', 'Contents');
        $file = Storage::disk('public')->get($file_name);
        $filepath = storage_path("app/{$data->file}");
        
        return \Response::download($filepath);
    }
}
```

**viewfile.blade.php**

```
@foreach($downloads as $down)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$down -> name}}</td>
        <td>{{$down -> directory}}</td>
        <td>{{$down -> updated_at}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{url('/download/'.$down->name)}}" download="{{$down-> name}}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are all of the downloadable files in the root of the `storage/app/public` directory or are some nested?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/20415444/4650866

Comment: There are all saved in a storage/app/public/hi directory

Answer (score 3):

First, you must run this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

For example:

```
Route::get('/download', function (){
    return Storage::download('public/file_name.png');
});
```

[You can find documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files)