# How can I download pdf from the storage folder using laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My all files path is `/storage/app/public/applicants/pdf/[all-files-here]`. So, how can I download it from the folder.

I have done this:

```
$file = Storage::disk('public')->get('/applicants/' . 'selection_test_result_1669368177.pdf');

return response()->download($file);
```

Comment: what is the issue with this?

Comment: Also, possible dups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315857/cannot-download-file-from-storage-folder-in-laravel-5-4 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142831/how-to-download-file-from-storage-app-folder-in-laravel-8

Answer (score -1):

```
return Storage::download('file.pdf', $name, $headers);
```