# download existing zip folder from laravel storage

Tags: laravel, zip, laravel-livewire

I have a zip folder under storage and I want to download this folder whenever I click a button. But my code does not work. What is the problem?

here's my livewire component

```php
<div class="my-auto">
        <a type=button wire:click="downloadKit" style="border-radius:4px" class="">{{ __('Download') }}</a>
    </div>
```

```php
public function downloadKit(){
        $file = Storage::disk('public')->get('kit.zip');
    
        return (new Response($file, 200));
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415444/download-files-in-laravel-using-responsedownload

Answer (score 0):

You can return a file response like this
`return Storage::download("/path/to/kit.zip", "kit.zip");`

The path will be relative to /storage/app