# Laravel Content-Length header can't be sent with file response

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-8, response

I'm actually trying to send the Content-Length header with my file response (for downloading status bar purproses on client side) using this method :

```
return response()->header('Content-Length', $fileSize)->file($this->filesPath.$fileName);
```

But i'm getting an error :

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory::header does not exist. in file /www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php on line 113
```

It seems that the method is not recognized when there is "file()" in the response.

Here are my response headers :

[image: My headers]

Note : Apache webserver based on Linux machine running Laravel 8 with PHP 8.1

**Aditional informations :**

After testing on different environements and with multiples files, i've found out that the `Content-Length` header is working only with images. I've tested it in Laravel 9 & 8 and still can't send `Content-Length` header manually. Any other header is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download files in laravel using Response::download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415444/download-files-in-laravel-using-responsedownload)

Answer (score 0):

Use the pre-built [`download()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-downloads) method to send headers

```
$filesPath = 'path/to/file'; // change this
$fileName = 'file-name'; // change this
$fileSize = 'size'; // change this

$headers = [
    'Content-Length' => $fileSize
];

return response()->download($filesPath, $fileName, $headers);
```

Comment: Tried :

`        return response()->download($this->filesPath.$fileName, $fileName, [
            'Content-Length' => $fileSize,
            'X-FileSize'    => $fileSize,
        ]);`

But any of both headers is working..